# Error: "-[NSCFString sizeWithTextStyle:]: unrecognized selector" in IPhone SDK

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, ios4

I get the following error while running my app.

**'-[NSCFString sizeWithTextStyle:]: unrecognized selector**

I have not used sizeWithTextStyle in my entire project.

So what could be wrong?

I get error on `return pos;` statement below

**Code:**

```
(UIView *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView viewForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
     UIView *pos = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0.0,0.0,320.0,35.0)];
     return pos;
}
```

**Error in Console:**

`Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[NSCFString sizeWithTextStyle:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7044b50'`

Because of indentation problem while putting whole crash log here, I am putting the screenshot of the crash log

[image]

Comment: hard to say without some more code. Could you provide the code lines where your app crashes?

Comment: @Philipp Jaquet: I have edited my question and added my code. I have tried debugging the code and found that app crashes out with a **SIGNAL ABORT** statement

Answer (score 29, accepted):

I think, the problem is somewhere else, not in this line of code. The object is not able to retain itself. Post the code, where you are using the `sizeWithTextStyle` method

Have you the -all_load flag on your link settings?

This issue comes up a lot. **You need to add -all_load and -ObjC to your applications link flags.**

**EDIT : **

Crash appears to occur on line:

```
 CGSize textSize = [self.text sizeWithTextStyle:textStyle];
 in class: CPTextLayer method: sizeToFit

 which is called from within class CPTextLayer method initWithText:
-(id)initWithText:(NSString *)newText style:(CPTextStyle *)newStyle
....
[self sizeToFit];


**try to set with iOS 4 and not with 3.1.3 **
```

Comment: I had already used -ObjC and I also tried putting **-all_load** flag and then Clean All & Build and Run but it still crashes at the same place. What can be done?

Comment: I am not using this method `sizeWithTextStyle` anywhere in my code. Can you please suggest where could it be getting referenced?

Comment: -sizeWithTextStyle: is an NSString category method added by Core Plot. I agree that you probably have a linker error.

Comment: Nice one, do you have a tech explanation for this?

Answer (score 4):

When you have memory management issues (selectors being sent to the wrong instances is one symptom of memory management issues), there are a number of things you can do:

1. Re-read the Cocoa [memory management rules](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/MemoryMgmt/Articles/mmRules.html) and make sure that you're following them.
2. Run the [static analyser](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#featuredarticles/StaticAnalysis/). This will often pick up places where you have neglected the memory management rules.
3. Try using [`NSZombieEnabled`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Xcode/Conceptual/iphone_development/130-Debugging_Applications/debugging_applications.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007959-CH7-SW3) to find out whether [and when] you are sending messages to unallocated instances.

Answer (score 3):

I am also getting same error but now it's solved.

Need to do simple thing, set the value of Other linker flag.

below I have mention the steps.

Project name - Build Setting - Other linker flag (use search bar to search) - "-ObjC"

Comment: Can you paste the photo of this Because I have found out only debug and release and nothing else in the Other Linker Flag

Answer (score 0):

You should change your code to use pointers like this:

```
UIView *pos = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0.0,0.0,320.0,35.0)]; 
     return pos;
```

Pay attention to asterisk!

And of course the `;` in the end of allocation statement!

Comment: I tried that but still it does crash with the same error. What can be done?

Comment: did you try to clean up your project and build again? Also can you put the crash log? I think it doesn't crash on this specific line...

Comment: Yeah Nava Carmon. It was just that I missed out on semicolon while copying the code. Also I tried cleaning but still it doesn't work.

Comment: I have added the Console Error message in my question.

Comment: can you post your whole table view delegate source? May be you release something that is been autoreleased like creating a view from the main bundle, assigning it somewhere and release and so on? This can cause a memory corruption and just crash anywhere... Lines you've posted can't cause the crash. memory corruption, that happens in one of your table view delegate's functions is causing it. please post some more code.