# Implement plot Graph in iPhone using core-plot

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, xcode4, core-plot

I am trying to implementing plot graphs using the link.

http://www.switchonthecode.com/tutorials/using-core-plot-in-an-iphone-application

But as for support i need to add plot files & frameworks.

[How to install CorePlot framework correctly?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6826259/how-to-install-coreplot-framework-correctly)

**`I am using xcode 4.1`**

Copy the CorePlotHeaders to my Xcode project

Copy libCorePlotCocoaTouch.a to my Xcode project

Add to **Other Linker Flags** in my target *build settings*: **-ObjC -all_load**

in **`xcode 4.1`**

***`And please provide me any other best tutorials for Graph applications in xcode4.1`***

I have an error causes to crash the app

*Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[NSCFString sizeWithTextStyle:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x4e88e20'*

Call stack at first throw:
(
    0   CoreFoundation                      0x012865a9 __exceptionPreprocess + 185

```
1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x000b4313 objc_exception_throw + 44
2   CoreFoundation                      0x012880bb -[NSObject(NSObject)
```

doesNotRecognizeSelector:] + 187

```
3   CoreFoundation                      0x011f7966 ___forwarding___ + 966
4   CoreFoundation                      0x011f7522 _CF_forwarding_prep_0 + 50
5   ESPT                                0x00031b60 -[CPTTextLayer sizeThatFits] + 125
6   ESPT                                0x00031cab -[CPTTextLayer sizeToFit] + 62
7   ESPT                                0x000316bf -[CPTTextLayer initWithText:style:] + 188
8   ESPT                                0x0002bf69 -[CPTAxis
```

Comment: Please follow the below link. It contains how to install core-plot library in our project and explains how to draw a scatter plot. Hope you find solution when you follow this. http://www.johnwordsworth.com/2011/10/adding-charts-to-your-iphone-ipad-app-using-core-plot/

Comment: Yes this is the nice tutorial for xcode 4

Comment: possible duplicate of [Error: "-\[NSCFString sizeWithTextStyle:\]: unrecognized selector" in IPhone SDK](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5040067/error-nscfstring-sizewithtextstyle-unrecognized-selector-in-iphone-sdk)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Go to your project's **Build Settings** -> **Linking Options**.

See here :

[image]

Comment: I dont have other linkeflag . ok i i have other LD Flag... how to add -ObjC -all_load at there? see my edit ques with diagrum

Comment: @Ranga just click on the **Debug** AND **Release** sub-fields, edit and that's it! :-)